# What are the pro and cons with a hybrid app with both webviews and native views?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, uiwebview, webview

Its quite clear what are the pros and cons of chosing a application with webviews instead of native views. But I was thinking about making a hybrid, with both webviews and native views - giving me the best from each camp.

What are the pros and cons going for a hybrid solution?

Answer (score 2):

The only good reason to make a webapps / "hybrid" is cross-platform compability, but (my opinion), it's the best way to make poor application.

User should feel right at home with your app, if most android apps use same guidelines / icon set / view components, it's a bad idea to make your own.

This slideshow should be useful to you, it's about android design practices:
http://www.slideshare.net/AndroidDev/android-ui-design-tips

Answer (score 1):

Mixing native functionality with web app functionality (especially when the HTML/CSS/JS is generated by the native app) works quite seamlessly. I have screens that mix both native and web on the same display, allowing me to use the best of both worlds.

The major downside is in creating a common look and feel between the two worlds. For example, a native list view (default white on black, with block elevator bar) looks very different to a web list view unless you put lots of effort in replicating the native behavior in your CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Pros: Little less Development to compatible with all devices.

Cons: Hybrid apps are just web apps with native wrapper. I don't like hybrid app ..

Answer (score 0):

As im HTML 5 Developer,

If your hybrid app content high end animation using webkit or kinda game... you should better go with native for android & ios 5.

As of my experience in android webkit animations are bit slow sometimes stucks.

As of Ios4.3 its perfect and again as of ios 5 its same as of in android bit too slow.

And avoid using framework like jQuery which slow down your html 5 apps.

Note : if you are going to involves with web app better use any HTML 5 framework like Phonegap etc... and also you should consider Titanium.

UPDATE : Due to html5 cache limits in IOS 5 ...My Game looks sluggy ...